# Spring security, No HttpSession currently exists after succession login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

After the successful login, session is getting invalidated immediately and redirected to login page.
Sometimes, while the user is accessing the application itself, user is getting kicked out, because of invalid session.

Without calling the session invalidate function, my user session is getting lost.

Spring Security Version 3.0

> Spring Security XML

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- <security:http pattern="login" security="none"/> -->
    <!-- <security:http pattern="*" use-expressions='true'>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="user/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginError" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" />
    </security:http> -->
   <!--  <security:http pattern="/index" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/loginError" security="none" /> -->
    <security:http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/img/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/fonts/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/less/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/docs/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/dashboard-assets/**" security="none"/>

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
     <security:csrf/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logoutSession*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginError*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/cancelChangePassword*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/updatePassword*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/changePassword*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/order/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/master/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/segment/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/agency/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/promotional/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/device/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/customNotification/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/feedback/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATL','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/store/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_HO','ROLE_SA','ROLE_BDATLS','ROLE_MARKET')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_HO')" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/index" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginError?error" 
                                always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/nourlhere" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/logoutSession" >
            <security:concurrency-control expired-url="/logoutSession" max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </security:session-management>

        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/welcome"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="sessionValidtion" after="LAST"/>

        <security:remember-me use-secure-cookie="true" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>

    </security:http>



    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.ust.wmi.lakshya.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />
<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.ust.wmi.lakshya.handler.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder">
    <!-- <constructor-arg index="0" value="256"/> -->
</bean>
<bean id="sessionValidtion" class="com.wmi.lakshya.web.resource.SessionValidation"></bean>
</beans>
```

> Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>web app Project</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oms-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oms-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/oms-mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CacheFilterOneDay</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ust.wmi.lakshya.filter.CacheHeaderFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>CacheTime</param-name>
            <param-value>2629746000</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilterOneDay</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilterOneDay</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilterOneDay</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilterOneDay</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilterOneDay</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <path>/</path>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Debug log

> 2016-02-18T12:43:17.241508+00:00 app[web.2]: DEBUG [18.02.16 12:43:17]
>   HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
>   2016-02-18T12:43:17.241631+00:00 app[web.2]: DEBUG [18.02.16 12:43:17]
>   HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was
>   available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.